# Retrieve binary representation of number in ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I would like to get the binary form of a number, e.g 6 -> "0110"

I've tried `(js/toString ...)` but no matter what syntax I use, the repl always returns `"[object Window]"`. What does this mean?

I'm also confused because toString is part of goog.math.Integer, and yet when I try to use js/isOdd, part of the same library, it says it is not defined. I tried manually requiring it via `(ns user (:require [goog.math.Integer :as int]))`, but it made no difference.

I'm also confused as to the difference between `(.toString ...)` and `(js/toString ...)`.

Any help with the specific problem and/or the nuances of js functions in cljs would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `(6).toString(2)` works for me…

Comment: in a clojurescript repl? This sort of syntax doesn't even look like lisp to me, and my repl says it's illegal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a parser error, there are three ways to make this work, creating a `var` with the number and calling `.toString` on that, writing the number with an extra a dot or writing the number in parentheses.

If you try `6.toString(2)` on a JavaScript console you will get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

But this `6..toString(2)` works. This is because the JavaScript parser expects a number followed by a dot to be a float literal. When you write `6.` the parser expects the next character to be a number not `t`, when you write `6..` the first dot is parsed as part of the number (creating the number 6.0) and the second dot is parsed as a method call on the created number.

In ClojureScript the compiler knows about this "feature" of JavaScript so you can pass the 6 literal to `toString`:

```
cljs.user> (.toString 6 2)
"110"
cljs.user> (.toString 6. 2)
"110"
```

The ClojureScript compiler generates the correct code in both cases. In the first case it generates `(6).toString(2)` and in the second case it generates `6.0.toString(2)`.

`(js/toString 6)` is calling the `toString` defined on the `window` global object. No matter what you pass the result is always the same. You can check that calling by `window.toString()` in a JavaScript console.

`(.toString target args)` is calling the `toString` defined in the target object passing args as parameters of the method.

Comment: Interesting, `(.toString 6. 2)` worked, but `(.toString 6 2)` gave an illegal syntax error. What would cause this?

Comment: @Phylth strange, I tested both forms in a ClojureScript REPL. Which version of ClojureScript are you using? I tested in the following versions _0.0-2371_ and _0.0-2755_. How do you start a cljs REPL?

Comment: I've been using 0.0-2156 and starting a browser repl from Sublimetext. I haven't even been able to start one with any other version. It keeps throwing a clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo. It's quite possible that the older version is the reason though

Comment: Yeah, this bug was fixed in 0.0-2261. See issue [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-715?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) and commit [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/f0dcc75573a42758f8c39b57d1747a2b4967327e). Maybe you can create another question describing this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `(.toString 6 2)`.  Using `(js/toString ...)` amounts to `toString(...)` which you can try evaluating yourself in a typical javascript browser console. You'll see you'll also get an "object Window".

`(js/thing)` is used for referring to a javascript runtime symbol. In particular, if you've loaded code separate from your compiled clojurescript (e.g. loaded through a different script), you can refer to the loaded symbols using the `js/...` syntax. `js/thing`, in this case, will refer to `thing` in the top level scope of javascript.

For example, say you're using the ROT.js library which exposes its API through the ROT object. You can access its functions in clojurescript (assuming the library has been loaded), using `js/ROT`. Creating an instance of its Display object found in ROT.Display would then be accomplished using `(js/ROT.Display. params)`.

Loaded Closure compatible code, on the other hand, is accessed depending on how they've been required in the namespace. In general, if you've loaded the `goog.math` library with `(ns test (:require [goog.math :as math])`, you can access everything under `goog.math` using `(math/something)`.

The `(.function object params)` syntax is used for calling methods of a javacript object and would correspond to `object.function(params)`. Remember that javascript objects are different from values and objects you create through pure clojurescript code. Use `(.-property object)`, if you just want to get the value of that object's property instead. You can also lookup `doto`, `..`, and the threading macros `->`, `->>` for more ways to deal with javascript objects inside clojurescript. Most of the interop facilities provided for java in clojure holds for javascript/clojurescript. I also recommend reading http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/.

As for the `isOdd`, that is an instance method of an instance of `goog.math.Integer`. First create an instance of that (e.g. `(def e (new math/Integer ...)`) and then you can call `.isOdd` on that instance. Look through the [goog.math.Integer](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_math_Integer.html) documentations to see which static properties and methods are accessible straight from the Integer scope.

Comment: Hmm, `(.toString 6 2)` results in `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` for me. Your explanation of the different syntaxes is very helpful though, thanks.